# Trouble creating first game in Python! Syntax Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, syntax, control-flow

https://repl.it/@Zzoltang/FirstGame#main.py

I am trying to create a game where the user makes a set of choices which leads them down a path to victory or failure.

I created an option to choose a special power - but I don't know how to incorporate it into the game.

I am getting a syntax error for line 32. I am trying to make it so that if they chose invisibility they can make it down the path without losing health but if they chose strength they lose health.

thank you!!

Comment: Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In other words, please post your code on the question itself.

Comment: It seems that in line 28, you have not printed anything. That is 1 issue that you can resolve.

Answer (score 0):

In Python syntax, an if statement looks like this:

```
if something == "something else":
   executeCode()
```

It looks like you forgot to include `:` at the end of your if statement.

Good luck on your game :)

Comment: WOW of course I would make that mistake. THANK YOU. It seems that now, however, my code is not providing the print statement after I ask it to depending on what power they have